# Restore master DB to default(as just installed) without backup

Tags: sql-server-2012

I know this is not a reasonable request but is it possible to reset master DB to the status it was just installed without backup?

I deployed a DB project which I didn't know it will mess with master DB so I didn't backup it in advance plus the deployment script has some defects so the process failed and left tons of rubbishes in master DB.

I did a bit search but most of the instruction requires a backup whereas I can't be sure for those don't request backup can work master DB around or not.

Is there any way else except reinstalled the instance all over?

Comment: Please check out out similar a question at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21675409/503046) as well.

Comment: Apparently, I didn't search with correct keywords, option 4 did solve my problem, thanks!